# issue in setting multiple Alarm android?

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-broadcast

I am trying to set multiple alarm using broadcast receiver. I set repetition after every 1 minute and 30 seconds for two alarms But when I am receiving alarms both are repeating at same time.

I am doing this like:

```
if(repeat.equals("No Repeat")){
                    bcr.CancelAlarm(getApplicationContext());
                }
                else if(repeat.equals("After 10 Minutes")) {
                    bcr.TenMintAlarm(getApplicationContext(), hour, minute, dueDate,task_note,Tasks_ID);
                }
                else if(repeat.equals("After 15 Minutes")){
                    bcr.FifteenMintAlarm(getApplicationContext(), hour, minute, dueDate,task_note,Tasks_ID);
                }
                else if(repeat.equals("After n Minutes")){
                    bcr.nMintAlarm(getApplicationContext(), hour, minute, dueDate,task_note,Tasks_ID);
                }
```

BROADCAST RECEIVER:

```
public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
public void TenMintAlarm(Context context,int hour,int minutes, String duedate,String task_note,int task_id) 
{
    AlarmManager Alarm1 = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("NOTE", note);
    intent.putExtra("ID", task_id);
    int mUniqID = task_id+2;
    PendingIntent recurringAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, mUniqID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    System.out.println("mUniqID-----" +mUniqID);
    Alarm1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, _alarm, 1000 * 60, recurringAlarm);
}
public void FifteenMintAlarm(Context context, int hour,int minutes, String duedate, String task_note, int task_id)
{
    AlarmManager Alarm2 = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    i.putExtra("NOTE", note);
    i.putExtra("ID", task_id);
    int uniqID = task_id+2;
    System.out.println("mUniqID-----" +uniqID);
    PendingIntent Alarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, uniqID, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Alarm2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, _alarm, 1000 * 30, Alarm);
}
```

But when alarm receive it is repeating at same time instead of that I want that one alarm repeat after 1 minute and second after 30 seconds. Any suggestion may be helpful. thanks.

Comment: Are you sure about that bot alarm called ?

Comment: I'm afraid both your alarm IDs in `PendingIntent` are always the same, hence overwriting the other alarm. Check whether the IDs are different first if you want to have multiple alarms.

Comment: @AM, Yes both alarm I am receiving on time but issue is both are repeating on same time, but I have two different value one is four 30 second and second is for 1 minute. but both are repeating after 1 minute.

Comment: @antimo I have passed task id so task id always be different in pending intent for tow different alarm. I can see both are receiving different ID's.

Answer (score 0):

According to your else-if blocks, only one Alarm will be set depending on the condition you specify. If you want to set 2 Alarms, then you should put them in the same block or something.

Comment: can you please let me know how can i overcome this?

Comment: I am receiving booth alarm but it is repeating at same time. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different id's for `pending intent`. `mUniqID` and `uniqID` you used in both functions are equal, make `BroadcastReciever` thinks it is the same as other one so they fires at the same time. Just set those to different numbers.

```
public void TenMintAlarm(Context context,int hour,int minutes, String duedate,String task_note,int task_id) 
{
    AlarmManager Alarm1 = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("NOTE", note);
    intent.putExtra("ID", task_id);
    int mUniqID = 20;//change in here
    PendingIntent recurringAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, mUniqID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    System.out.println("mUniqID-----" +mUniqID);
    Alarm1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, _alarm, 1000 * 60, recurringAlarm);
}
public void FifteenMintAlarm(Context context, int hour,int minutes, String duedate, String task_note, int task_id)
{
    AlarmManager Alarm2 = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    i.putExtra("NOTE", note);
    i.putExtra("ID", task_id);
    int uniqID = 10;//change in here
    System.out.println("mUniqID-----" +uniqID);
    PendingIntent Alarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, uniqID, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Alarm2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, _alarm, 1000 * 30, Alarm); 
}
```